# Duplicate file on sd card

Tags: java, android, file

My application gets a shared image from gallery using

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

I want to be able to duplicate the file(new name) in the same location of the original file.

i am able to do this when the file is located in the internal storage, like this:

```
String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(this, imageUri);
String filePathNew = filePath;
int index = filePathNew.lastIndexOf('.');
filePathNew = filePathNew.substring(0, index) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + filePathNew.substring(index);

File fOrig = new File(filePath);
File f = new File(filePathNew);
try {
    copy(fOrig,f);
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    MyLogger.log(ShareActivity.this, MyLogger.ERROR, e + "|||" + MyLogger.getStackTrace(e));
    e.printStackTrace();
}


public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MyLogger.log(context, MyLogger.ERROR, "Error getting Real path from URI" + ex + "|||" + MyLogger.getStackTrace(ex));
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "NaN";
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

when the shared image is from the sd card. i get an exception

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:942)

URI path from EXTRA_STREAM:
/external/images/media/37713 
URI Real Path:
/storage/0709-9CE1/raz test/raz.jpg
```

AndroidManifest permissions:
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
INTERNET

I am testing on Galaxy S7 with android 6.0.1 but the issue was raised from other users also

What am i missing?

Comment: Please post the permissions used in the manifest

Comment: also which android version you test on?

Comment: manifest permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: i am testing on my Galaxy S7 android 6.0.1

but similar issue was raised by other users

Comment: Please do not misuse the comments for additional (large) info. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that your code doesn't contain Android permission and you'll using android 6.x, based on the error you need to add to get permission to write on external storage before you save your file.
you need to add something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RESULT);}
            else {
//your treatment

}
```

and check permission is needed to any operation that you'll do which is mentioned as permission on manifest.xml